# Favicon is not showing in chrome

Tags: html, opencart, opencart2.x

In my opencart 2 theme favicon is showing wrong in live link. It works properly in firefox, safari etc..But showing wrong favicon in chrome only. Is there any solution??

Comment: First this can be cache problem, second check the icon file which you are using i.e: .png or .ico, make it .ico it will work.

Comment: Yeah..Thankyou....In my default file another favicon.ico is already there..Now I replaced it with mine ...Issue solved

Comment: Welcome UI, Please like the answer below for same !

Answer (score 1):

First this can be cache problem, second check the icon file which you are using i.e: .png or .ico, make it .ico it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared your cache on your chrome browser via *crtl+F5*?

If this doesn't work can use the console output to provide more information?

Comment: Welcome here in stack :), this suit to be a comment better then an answer :). An answer provide final solution :). if the asker told you ctrl+F5 worked for him then u can post the first line of ur answer now :).

Comment: well i can't comment, due to the reputation requirement, can i?

Comment: Ah ok, so leave it as it is :) and let the community decide what to do :).

Comment: are you able to show us the output from the console when loading the page on chrome?

Comment: Thankyou....In my default file another favicon.ico is already there..Now I replaced it with mine ...Issue solved